# MGT PeoplePicker selectionChanged event parameter type

Tags: spfx-webparts, people-picker, react, microsoft-graph, graph-api

I am creating a SPFx web part and I am using the [Microsoft Graph Toolkit PeoplePicker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/people-picker). It offers a `selectionChanged` callback. This callback gets passed a parameter of type `Event` (defined in `typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`)

```
export type PeoplePickerProps = {
    // ....
    selectionChanged?: (e: Event) => void;
}
```

However, according to [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/mgt-react#usage) I need to access `event.target.selectedPeople`. But `selectedPeople` does not exist as property of `target`.

My code looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { PeoplePicker, People } from '@microsoft/mgt-react/dist/es6/spfx';

export const EmployeePicker: React.FC = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const [people, setPeople] = React.useState([]);

  const handleSelectionChanged = (event: Event): void => {
    console.log('Selection changed');
    console.log('event', event);
    setPeople(event.target.selectedPeople);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <PeoplePicker selectionChanged={handleSelectionChanged} />
      Selected People:
      <People people={people} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'd like to avoid opting out of the type system. (I guess changing the type of `event` to `any` would work) And rather know how I can access the `event.target.selectedPeople` prop using typescripts type system.

Comment: In documentation link you provided, they have not explicitly mentioned `Event` as type in callback function (`handleSelectionChanged()`).

Comment: @GaneshSanap They do not mention the `Event` type there, but they use `e.target.selectedPeople`. So I'd assume that this prop is how to access the selected people. However `Event` type does not have a `.target.selectedPeople` prop, which is the root cause for my confusion.

Comment: Yes, but standard [Event type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) don't always have all the properties under `target` property.